# Little and Mere

Tags: grammar

Sentences with the word *little*:

> - **How dare you, you are only a little rickshaw-puller hassling with me.**
>     (I'm not using the word  *little* for his age)
> - **Give me a little soil.**
> - **What can I do with this little soil.**
>     (I'm using the word *little* for the amount of soil)

Now, a sentence with the word *mere*:

> - **"How much more foolish it would be for mere humans to criticize “the Judge of all the earth"**
>     (in this sentence, *mere* mean something like "Not so special")

**Question:** 
Can I use "little" instead of "mere" in this sentence?

Also, can I write:

> **Men are made of mere soil, but they like to be jealous**

I hope you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

For your second quote is from the Bible, which has an archaic lexis, I would leave the sentence as it is.

But, if you intend to change it, come hell and high water, you can do that.

In that case, the meaning would shift to something else the original sentence is not trying to get across.

**Mere** in this sense indicates that man is almost nothing compared to the greatness of the Lord.

Replacing it with **little**, it would mean that man is little, the Lord above can anytime destroy him (though He won't), so he shouldn't think too much of himself.

The **mere soil** part does sound quite odd to me, I would replace it with *Man is made merely of soil.* and there's to it.

Comment: So my first these 3 sentences correct?